# Highcharts - How to set a gradient theme for each type of graph globally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I'm trying to set global options into Highcharts so when I create a new graph it is styled exactly like the rest of my other graphs, I've managed to set a global color arrays replacing the original one, and one type of gradients that is used for all my graphs.
Now i'd like to have a different type of gradient for each type of graph (spline, column, pie, area, etc)

Does anyone has an idea on how to proceed ?

(BTW I use React that's why I have to call Highcharts.Highcharts to access the object)

```js
import Highcharts from 'react-highcharts'

const colors = ['#3B86FF', '#77E5AA', '#093fb9', '#6d00f6', '#FF006E', '#FFBE0B', '#1EFFBC', '#ff8b12']
const gradients = ['#87B5FF', '#9AFFC9', '#0078ff', '#852cf5', '#FC3C8F', '#FFD41F', '#7CFFD8', '#FFB364']

export default Highcharts.Highcharts.setOptions({
  colors: Highcharts.Highcharts.map(colors, (color, i) => ({
    linearGradient: {
      x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1
    },
    stops: [
      [0, color],
      [1, gradients[i]]
    ]
  }))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired result by using `setOptions` again like this:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
  plotOptions: {
    line: {
        //color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0] - by default
    },
    spline: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
    },      
    column: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
    }, 
    pie: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3]
    }
  }
});
```

`plotOptions.{your series type}` describes default options for every series of the given type.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d68m2qq8/

Comment: thanks for the response, but in this case i can have only one colour per plot. If I have an areachart with multiple lines,, each line would be the same colour no ?